# How to select multiple rows using one query

Tags: t-sql

Is it possible to select multiple rows using one query in SQL Server? For example, I have to run two queries to get my results as follows. How can I achieve the results using one query?

```
SELECT col1, col2
WHERE order_number = 'unique_value1'

SELECT col1, col2
WHERE order_number = 'unique_value2'
```

Answer (score 1):

The first query is the fastest, with an iNDEX on order_number

> ```
> CREATE TABLE mytable (col1 int, col2 int, order_number varCHAR(50))
> GO
> ```

> ```
> SELECT col1, col2
> frOM mytable
> WHERE order_number = 'unique_value1'
> UNION
> SELECT col1, col2
> frOM mytable
> WHERE order_number = 'unique_value2'
> ```

> ```
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> col1 | col2
> ---: | ---:
> ```

> ```
> SELECT col1, col2
> frOM mytable
> WHERE order_number = 'unique_value1' OR order_number = 'unique_value2'
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> col1 | col2
> ---: | ---:
> ```

> ```
> SELECT col1, col2
> frOM mytable
> WHERE order_number IN ( 'unique_value1' ,'unique_value2')
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> col1 | col2
> ---: | ---:
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=714febdc96eb95be80fdd70376b26fa0)*

Comment: Thanks, I'm good to go!

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to nbk's solution is using the `UNION ALL` clause like so:

```
SELECT col1, col2
WHERE order_number = 'unique_value1'

UNION ALL

SELECT col1, col2
WHERE order_number = 'unique_value2'
```

If you do add an index to the `order_number` field, you can test which query is faster in your case (either using the `OR` clause or `UNION ALL` clause), it just depends on the data and system.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server by itself allows the return of multiple resultsets via a stored procedure. What matters is your client calling the stored procedure and receiving the resultsets. This means you can do:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE p_FetchData
AS
BEGIN

SELECT col1, col2
from table1
WHERE order_number = 'unique_value1';

SELECT col1, col2
from table2
WHERE order_number = 'unique_value2';

END
```

Now if you really need one query with the same fields from the same table obviously you can easily do:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE p_FetchData
AS
BEGIN

SELECT col1, col2
from table1
WHERE order_number in ('unique_value1','unique_value2');

END
```